# Написать функцию которая бы находила все возможные комбинации чисел из массива

Tags: javascript, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста написать функцию, которая бы находила все возможные комбинации чисел из массива `number_massive`, сумма которых равна числу `number`, не могу понять

1. `number_massive` содержит, только уникальные положительные числа (**`> 0`**)
2. в комбинации не должно быть повторений чисел
3. все комбинации должны быть уникальными

---

```
number: 99
number_massive: [8, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 1]

function objectNumber(number_massive, number) {
    
    return [[1, 2], [3]];
}
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! Вопросы должны также содержать попытки автора решить задачу, без них (попыток), вопрос будет являться учебным заданием. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: А чем не устроил мой ответ-решение на другом форуме?